# Link to Hotmail / Windows Live email compose -- maintaining BCC

Tags: email, url, hotmail, webmail

My app creates a mailto-esque link that takes the end user to a Hotmail compose screen with various attributes pre-filled.  Most of the functionality I need is working: to, cc, subject, body.  However, Hotmail seems to be stripping out any BCC attributes that I pass into the URL.

For example, this link works as advertised:

http://mail.live.com/mail/EditMessageLight.aspx?n=&to=bcc_for_privacy@email.com&cc=add1@email.com;%20add2@email.com&subject=the%20subject&body=the%20body

I get the one email address in the To field and two in the CC field.  But when I try the exact same URL except substituting "bcc" for "cc", the two addresses are nowhere to be found.

http://mail.live.com/mail/EditMessageLight.aspx?n=&to=bcc_for_privacy@email.com&bcc=add1@email.com;%20add2@email.com&subject=the%20subject&body=the%20body

This link format is posted all over the web (along with a variation like http://mail.live.com/default.aspx?rru=compose%3f[attributes] ), but none of the various settings that I've tried actually work to bring in the BCC addresses.

I need the BCC so that the email recipients are not given each others' email addresses.  My versions of this url for regular old mailto, along with Gmail and Yahoo Mail, work perfectly.  Surprise surprise.