# URL to compose a message in Gmail (with full Gmail interface and specified to, bcc, subject, etc.)

Tags: url, hyperlink, gmail, query-string

I found a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4982702/what-is-the-format-of-compose-links-to-web-mail-clients-such-as-gmail-yahoo-mail) that provides an example for a link which opens just a compose message window. However, I would like it to open a window with the *full Gmail interface* but ready to compose a new message.

Of course this works:

https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#compose

But, I would also like to add a subject, to, bcc, etc. I tried something like the following, but to no avail:

https://mail.google.com/mail/?to=inbox@example.com&bcc=admin@example.com&subject=Hey#compose

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: The URL from the answer below doesn't seem to work, did you find a way to achieve that?

Comment: Is there any way where we can open mail window as if its reply to or forward via url ? So that users can directly forward or can reply to email.

Comment: @Kartik, I've created a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28671113/edit-or-forward-an-existing-mail-into-gmail-compose-window). Unfortunately, no answers yet. Do you know how to achieve that?

Answer (score 218, accepted):

This seems to work (for now):

https://mail.google.com/mail/?view=cm&fs=1&to=someone@example.com&su=SUBJECT&body=BODY&bcc=someone.else@example.com

Comment: do you know how to set the from parameter? I have in my gmail several accounts to select from when sending... and I'd like to be able to set a desired one via url parameter

Comment: How about using the Plus sign '+' with that method? Going to https://mail.google.com/mail/?view=cm&fs=1&to=name+extra@gmail.com doesn't resolve the +.

Comment: @cronoklee I know it's old, but maybe someone could use it... for google apps, use http://mail.google.com/a/domain.com/mail?view=cm...

Comment: Is there any way where we can open mail window as if its reply to or forward via url ? So that users can directly forward or can reply to email.

Comment: @floribon You can attribute a name alongside the email in the tranditional manner: "name <extra@gmail.com>" - https://mail.google.com/mail/?view=cm&fs=1&to=name%20%3Cextra@gmail.com%3E (hover over the name to see the email address in the page)

Comment: @nxasdf thanks that's great to know, however that doesn't solve what I'm trying to achieve, which is writting to an email address that contains the plus sign on itself, like foo+bar at gmail.com.

Comment: @floribon Oh right, that's even easier :) replace `+` with the URL encoded `%2B` - https://mail.google.com/mail/?view=cm&fs=1&to=name%2Bextra@gmail.com

Comment: How can I send html formatted email, just link I want to send bold text, than what should I use?

Comment: It shows compose layout in full screen. Good but I'll choose this shortcut when it loads page faster. I watched loading bar for 2 or 3 seconds like I see it for regular gmail interface.

Comment: This link is not working in android chrome browser. When I click on the link it takes me to in the gmail inbox instead of gmail compose section.

Comment: Gowri: it works for me on Chrome on latest Android on a Nexus 6P.

Comment: @DS_web_developer I figured it out, just specify the email with the number after the url **https://mail.google.com/mail/u/#/**. It's probably to late now anyways but just felt like including that for future references.

Comment: For those using Google Apps, start the URL with "https://mail.google.com/mail/u/?authuser=your-email&view=cm&..." as the URLs including a number aren't reliable (the number can change when restarting the browser, e.g. the GMail one tends to be given to 0).

Comment: How can I encode a newline in the body?

Comment: Replace newlines with %0A

Answer (score 34):

I thought I'd try and consolidate the information from several good answers and comments and provide some additional information. Examples first then background and explanation of terminology below.

**N.B. All links will fall back to the default account if there is no match**

#### Simple Compose Link

Opens the inbox with a compose window in the bottom right

- Default account:
  `https://mail.google.com/mail/#compose`
- Specific account by index (second in this example):
  `https://mail.google.com/mail/u/1/#compose`
- Specific account by email address (lee@example.org in this example):
  `https://mail.google.com/mail/u/lee@example.org/#compose`
- Any account from specific domain (example.edu in this example):
  `https://mail.google.com/a/example.edu/mail/#compose`
- From specific delegated mailbox (id abcd1234efgh5678 in this example):
  `https://mail.google.com/mail/d/abcd1234efgh5678/#compose`
- From specific delegated mailbox belonging to non-default account (id 1234efgh5678ijkl, fourth user):
  `https://mail.google.com/mail/u/3/d/1234efgh5678ijkl/#compose`

Each example above automatically redirects from `#compose` to `#inbox?compose=new`. You can use either URL.

#### Custom compose links

Include a to address, subject, body, cc and bcc by opening the Compose Message (cm) view directly. This opens the compose message view fullscreen (even without `fs=1` parameter). May struggle with some special characters in the URL.

- Default account:
  `https://mail.google.com/mail/?view=cm&to=morgan@example.com&su=SUBJECT&body=BODY&bcc=dakota@example.com`
- Specific account by index (second in this example):
  `https://mail.google.com/mail/u/1/?view=cm&to=morgan@example.com&su=SUBJECT&body=BODY&bcc=dakota@example.com`
- Specific account by email address (lee@example.org in this example):
  `https://mail.google.com/mail/u/lee@example.org/?view=cm&to=morgan@example.com&su=SUBJECT&body=BODY&bcc=dakota@example.com`
- Any account from specific domain (example.edu in this example):
  `https://mail.google.com/a/example.edu/mail/?view=cm&to=morgan@example.com&su=SUBJECT&body=BODY&bcc=dakota@example.com`
- From specific delegated mailbox (id abcd1234efgh5678 in this example):
  `https://mail.google.com/mail/d/abcd1234efgh5678/?view=cm&to=morgan@example.com&su=SUBJECT&body=BODY&bcc=dakota@example.com`
- From specific delegated mailbox belonging to non-default account (id 1234efgh5678ijkl, fourth user):
  `https://mail.google.com/mail/u/3/d/1234efgh5678ijkl/?view=cm&to=morgan@example.com&su=SUBJECT&body=BODY&bcc=dakota@example.com`

#### Complex compose links

Anything you can put in a `mailto:` link can be passed to Gmail. You need to [URL encode](https://www.urlencoder.io)* the mailto link first. This takes care of accented letters and other special characters that URLs can choke on:

```
mailto:morgan@example.com?subject=SUBJECT&body=BODY&bcc=dakota@example.com
  v  v  v  v  v  v 
mailto%3Amorgan%40example.com%3Fsubject%3DSUBJECT%26body%3DBODY%26bcc%3Ddakota%40example.com
```

- Default account:
  `https://mail.google.com/mail/?extsrc=mailto&url=mailto%3Amorgan%40example.com%3Fsubject%3DSUBJECT%26body%3DBODY%26bcc%3Ddakota%40example.com`
- Specific account by index (second in this example):
  `https://mail.google.com/mail/u/1/?extsrc=mailto&url=mailto%3Amorgan%40example.com%3Fsubject%3DSUBJECT%26body%3DBODY%26bcc%3Ddakota%40example.com`
- Specific account by email address (lee@example.org in this example):
  `https://mail.google.com/mail/u/lee@example.org/?extsrc=mailto&url=mailto%3Amorgan%40example.com%3Fsubject%3DSUBJECT%26body%3DBODY%26bcc%3Ddakota%40example.com`
- Any account from specific domain (example.edu in this example):
  `https://mail.google.com/a/example.edu/mail/?extsrc=mailto&url=mailto%3Amorgan%40example.com%3Fsubject%3DSUBJECT%26body%3DBODY%26bcc%3Ddakota%40example.com`
- From specific delegated mailbox (id abcd1234efgh5678 in this example):
  `https://mail.google.com/mail/d/abcd1234efgh5678/?extsrc=mailto&url=mailto%3Amorgan%40example.com%3Fsubject%3DSUBJECT%26body%3DBODY%26bcc%3Ddakota%40example.com`
- From specific delegated mailbox belonging to non-default account (id 1234efgh5678ijkl, fourth user):
  `https://mail.google.com/mail/u/3/d/1234efgh5678ijkl/?extsrc=mailto&url=mailto%3Amorgan%40example.com%3Fsubject%3DSUBJECT%26body%3DBODY%26bcc%3Ddakota%40example.com`

*More information on URL Encoding / Percent Encoding [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding). At the time of writing, [urlencoder.io](https://www.urlencoder.io) allows you to encode online and also has links to blog articles on how to URL Encode using a few common languages.

#### Background and Definitions

- You can log in to multiple Gmail and/or Google Workspace accounts.
- The first account you log into in a fresh browser becomes your **default account**.
- The default account can vary for you if you use different browsers or browser profiles. It can also change if you sign out, remove all accounts and sign back in in a different order.
- If you sign in to multiple accounts they are indexed in order of sign in. The **default account has an index of zero**. Navigating to `https://mail.google.com/mail/#inbox` will usually redirect you to your default account (index zero) if you are signed in to more than one account: `https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox`
- You can **specify a Google Workspace domain by inserting `/a/<domain>`** before `/mail` (whereas user index `/u/<index>` goes after `/mail`). This can be useful when you are providing a link internally in a company and you want the link to compose a new email in their work account (regardless of what order they signed in to their various accounts with)
- You can compose a message from a **delegated mailbox only if you know the delegation ID** (and the user index of the account with delegate permissions if not the default account):
  `https://mail.google.com/mail/d/ALGkd7w86mZOVigdDwK63uDpfMPlA2GJN7qSc4P7idKz7ffqTN0L/#compose`
  OR
  `https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/d/ALGkd7w86mZOVigdDwK63uDpfMPlA2GJN7qSc4P7idKz7ffqTN0L/#compose`
  OR, for user number 4,
  `https://mail.google.com/mail/u/3/d/ALGkd7w86mZOVigdDwK63uDpfMPlA2GJN7qSc4P7idKz7ffqTN0L/#compose`
  **Note:** The delegation ID is unique per user (different users will have different delegation IDs) and is subject to change (e.g. logging out and logging back in to your main Gmail account will generate a new delegation ID for the delegated account).
  To get the current delegation ID you can copy the URL for the delegated mailbox from your Gmail account switcher:
  [image: Copy the delegated mailbox URL to obtain the delegation ID]

Comment: Hi Matthew, 
Thank you for the detailed guide! I have several "send-as" addresses in my google workspace account. Do you know if it is possible to define the sender address from the URL as well? i tried adding &from=myspecificaddress@example.com in the url, with no success.

Comment: I can see how that would be handy for internal tools @Kev but I don't *think* it's possible. According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/9383777/145725 you can't do it and they point out that it doesn't make much sense for the standard use case (a mailto link on a public website).

Comment: @Matthew Is it possible to open email(its in Sent folder)  if I know that email Id and threadId?  Just to open only email not the whole thread if email was replied&

Comment: @Nyuokimi I'm not sure you can even do that using the GUI. Perhaps it depends on your threading settings but for me the only way I can view a reply I have sent is in the threaded conversation view. The only way I can see to get it out of the thread is to "Show original" (and view it with all its headers). I'm happy to try and dig in a bit more if you want to post a new question and share a link to it here?

Comment: @Matthew hERE is link to the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72182265/how-to-open-specific-email-without-whole-thread-in-gmail

Comment: @Matthew, "delegated mailbox only if you know the delegation ID" do you know how to find the delegation ID ? With some tests, it seems to be user specific and change over time/session ?

Comment: @EricMartin Yes it is user specific, but I didn't realise it changed with a new session. I have added some additional information to mention both of these facts and show one way to get the current delegation ID. I don't think the ID can be gleaned from the API (or command line tools like GAM)... according to https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.settings.delegates#Delegate, you can only see the delegated email address and the verification status

Comment: Thank you for the update. Google doc says : To access a delegated account, you can use the account switcher to switch between your account and other delegated accounts that you have access to.

For best results, delete any saved bookmarks.  So i guess those ids are token with time limit. If you hit an old link, you will be redirect with e new one

Answer (score 33):

Bookmarking this URL should give you a full-screen compose window, without any distractions:

https://mail.google.com/mail/?view=cm&fs=1&tf=1

Additionally, if you want to be future-proof (see for instance how other URLs in this question stopped working) you can bookmark a link to:

```
mailto:
```

It will open your default email client and you probably already have Gmail configured for that purpose.

Comment: perfect when you want to send someone a quick message without starting to go through your inbox!

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I was looking for: a distraction free way to send an email - just looking at the inbox sucks you in.  Wish I could upvote more than once!

Comment: `mailto:` link is gold!

Comment: This is great. I was able to add a shortcut to my taskbar that opens this and it works great. `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --app="https://mail.google.com/mail/?view=cm&fs=1&tf=1"`

Answer (score 13):

The GMail web client supports `mailto:` links

For regular `@gmail.com` accounts: `https://mail.google.com/mail/?extsrc=mailto&url=...`

For G Suite accounts on domain `gsuitedomain.com`: `https://mail.google.com/a/gsuitedomain.com/mail/?extsrc=mailto&url=...`

`...` needs to be replaced with a *urlencoded* `mailto:` link.

Demo: https://mail.google.com/mail/?extsrc=mailto&url=mailto%3A%3Fto%3Dsomeguy%40gmail.com%26bcc%3Dmyattorney%40gmail.com%2Cbuzzfeed%40gmail.com%26subject%3DHi%2520There%26body%3Dbody%2520goes%2520here

[Learn more about `mailto:` links by reading RFC6068](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6068)

Comment: Thanks for listing a source, and an RFC at that!  But I found one way gmail and the RFC are different: gmail uses `su=`, the RFC uses `subject=`.  Other than that, they appear identical.  RFC 2368 was also useful.

Answer (score 12):

It's worth pointing out that if you have multiple Gmail accounts, you may want to use the URL approach because you can customize which account to compose from.

e.g.

```
https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox?compose=new   
https://mail.google.com/mail/u/1/#inbox?compose=new
```

Or if you know the email address you are sending from, replace the numeric index with the email address:

```
https://mail.google.com/mail/u/your@email.com/#inbox?compose=new
```

Comment: Any way around the fact that this is dependent on the order that you signed into each account?

Comment: @Matt Yes, you can use https://mail.google.com/mail/u/your@email.com/#inbox?compose=new instead of the numeric index.

Comment: how to add recipient email? `compose=new&to=blahblah@gmail` isn't working

Answer (score 8):

https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/x/?&v=b&eot=1&pv=tl&cs=b

This link works for composing directly in m.gmail.com as mobile in a desktop browser. Why? It is really faster.

Comment: the link works and is fast. but not as OP requested which can pre-fill in bcc and cc also from URL.  Also it would have made it awesome if it could attach file using regular HTML input type file.

Answer (score 6):

For Chrome:

1. Set your email manager to Gmail

[image: gmail handler]

1. Write mailto: in the address bar and press enter.

Easier:

1. Edit search engines:

[image: Edit search engines]

[image: Edit search engines]

1. Write mt and enter in address bar.

Comment: Nice hack! ThaTsat's an niteresting method

Answer (score 4):

Many others have done an excellent job here giving a basic answer, especially [Tobias Mühl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53002257/2430549).  As mentioned, GMail's Api very closely matches the definition given by [RFC2368](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2368) and [RFC6068](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6068).  This is true of the extended form of the mailto: links, but it's also true in the commonly-used forms found in the other answers.  Of the five parameters, four are identical (such as `to`, `cc`, `bcc` and `body`) and one received only slight modification (`su` is gmail's version of `subject`).

If you want to know more about what you can do with *mailTo* gmail URLs, then these RFCs might be of help.  Unfortunately, Google has not published any source themselves.

To clarify the parameters:

- `to` - Email to who
- `su` (gmail API) / `subject` (mailTo API) - Email Title
- `body` - Email Body
- `bcc` - Email Blind-Carbon Copy
- `cc` - Email Carbon Copy address

Comment: Any parameter available to set address for "From"? I've connected my official emails with gmail.

Answer (score 0):

None of the other answers seem to address the original question which explicitly asks for the "full Gmail interface". I believe this means wanting to open a prefilled compose message in a *window* rather than the *fullscreen* interface.

**You cannot pre-populate fields in the windowed interface, only in the fullscreen one.**

The windowed interface only allows you to customize which account will be used to send the email, while the fullscreen interface allows you to send the 5 `mailto` parameters (e.g. "to", "body", etc.):

```
https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?tf=cm&to=to@example.com&cc=cc@example.com,cc2@example.com&bcc=bcc@example.com&su=subject+here&body=line1%0Aline2
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70030094/35690) for a lot of examples.

Answer (score 0):

If you're setting default email programs in linux, create this default script to make Gmail your default. Let's call it `new-email.sh` (You can pick your own). Create this script anywhere in your system and make it executable. `chmod 700 new-email.sh` Replace `firefox` with a web browser of your choice. Then pick that script (`new-email.sh`) in your linux system settings for your default email program. The parameters passed from the mailto links will be translated automagically. The body will also auto-populate - tested here: https://www.scottseverance.us/mailto.html

```
#!/bin/bash
ARGS=`echo $1 |  sed -E 's/(mailto:)([^?]+)([?])(.*$)/\2\&\4/g'|sed "s/subject=/su=/g"`
firefox "https://mail.google.com/mail/?view=cm&to=$ARGS"
```

Answer (score -1):

The example URLs for standard gmail, above, return a google error.

The February 2014 post to [thread 2583928](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2583928/prefilling-gmail-compose-screen-with-html-text) recommends replacing `view=cm&fs=1&tf=1` with `&v=b&cs=wh`.

Note: It also no longer seems possible to autopopulate the mail body.

Comment: March 2020: I can populate the email body just fine.

Answer (score -1):

```html
<a href="mailto:?subject=BlahBlah&body=Dear%20Name,%0D%0A%0D%0AI%20would%20like%20to%20take%20this%20pportunity%20to%20,%0D%0ABest%20regards">
```

I test this way for my website, and it's worked.
After "mailto:" write your the email you want to receive info.
"%20" means the letter space.
"%0D%0A%" means new paragraph.

Answer (score -2):

When you click on compose email in Gmail notice that the url changes from https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox to https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox?compose=new. Now when you enter say a email id xyz@gmail.com , the value for compose changes now the url became https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox?compose=150b0f7ffb682642.

So this is working fine with my html hyperlink until the account is signed in, but if the account is not signed in it would take me the login page and when I enter the credentials somehow this compose value is lost and this does not work.

Comment: `150b0f7ffb682642` is the ID of your email draft. This link only works when you're logged into your Gmail account. Other people clicking the link won't see the `xyz@gmail.com` as the recipient