# URI to compose gmail message with inner HTML

Tags: hyperlink, gmail, google-apps

Ahoy. In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8852679/64062), there is a way how to open *Compose* window in gmail.

Is there a way how to specify inner HTML inside body that it will send this:

[LINE1](http://stackoverflow.com)
***LINE2***

and not just this:

```
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com">LINE1</a><br><i><b>LINE2</b></i>
```

Thanks.

---

***Update:*** Just to specify ***link*** in email's **body** is fine. That's what I basically wanted in the first place.

Comment: Don't you think that would be sort of a security vulnerability?  What if you added in some hidden, malicious elements instead of a link and bold text?

Comment: Tim: Yes, it would very well be. But they could still provide limited set of HTML attributes passed in different (but defined) way. Like `&body_ext=[link:LINE1:http://stackoverflow.com]`.