# Is the mail.google.com "API" documented?

Tags: gmail

If you visit:

https://mail.google.com/mail/?view=cm&to=stacko%40barrycarter.info&su=Sending%20email%20from%20stack%20post&body=hi+barry+i+am+sending+you+email+from+a+stack+post

and are logged into gmail, you will see a "compose mail" window with a 
default subject and body text.

Is this documented anywhere? Are there other fields I can set (in 
addition to su= and body=)? Can I use POST if I want to pre-fill the 
composer with a long message?

Googling was unhelpful, but I might have been doing it wrong.

Comment: IF it is documented somewhere, it is here: https://developers.google.com/gmail/

Comment: I did visit https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/sendingmail before asking, but this appears to use Python functions (which, admittedly, may just be a wrapper around the URL version). I'm wondering if the 'raw' URL "API" is documented.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the google API is *mostly* in accordance with the *mailTo Api*, as defined in [RFC2368](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2368) and [RFC6068](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6068).  Of the five parameters, four are identical (such as `to`, `cc`, `bcc` and `body`) and one received only slight modification (`su` is gmail's version of `subject`).

In fact, it seems that the RFC's define extended url's, which take even more parameters and look like this: `https://mail.google.com/a/gsuitedomain.com/mail/?extsrc=mailto&url...`, and these URL's, also, work!  (Thanks to [Tobias Mühl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53002257/2430549) for discovering this!) Though, for the rest of us, `to=` and `body=` will be much simpler, but now there is a degree fo certainty in the API that they are following.

Unfortunately, I wasn't able to locate any official API published directly *by Google* themselves.

Parameters :

- `to` - Email to who
- `su` (gmail API) / `subject` (mailTo API) - Email Title
- `body` - Email Body
- `bcc` - Email Blind-Carbon Copy
- `cc` - Email Carbon Copy address

...are widely accepted and used by the community.  For instance, see this popular answer that accepts these parameters without providing documentation: [URL to compose a message in Gmail](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6548570/2430549).

So, your end result looks like...

```
https://mail.google.com/mail/?view=cm&to={email_address}&su={title}&body={url}&bcc={email_address}&cc={email_address}
```

This is just a summary of the Gmail-section of my Social Share URLs Github project - [Social Share URLs](https://github.com/bradvin/social-share-urls#gmail).

Answer (score -2):

The Gmail API is documented [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/). 
Disclaimer: The [send](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/send)  method is crap (i.e. poorly documented)