# mailto: for gmail etc from mobile device for angularjs web based application

Tags: html, angularjs, sendmail

I am working on an responsive web application where it is required to send mail,on browser if I am trying to do so it opens outlook using mailto: option,but it mobile it's not performing any operation as outlook is not available,what are the options to send mail via gmail or something when I open webpage on mobile device.

Kindly suggest

Comment: `mailto:` links will automatically open the device's default mail client. There is no method to force Gmail.

Comment: @BenM Same thing works well for browser,it opens up outlook but for mobile devices it doesn't perform any action,I am not able to debug also if there is any error.

Comment: What devices have you tested this on? `mailto:` works flawlessly on iOS and Android...

Comment: @BenM android only samsung

Comment: @BenM      var link = "mailto:" + email + "?subject=New%20email " + "&body=" + escape(body);
         window.location.href = link; I am using these line f code on button click to send mail

Comment: possible duplicate of [URL to compose a message in Gmail (with full Gmail interface and specified to, bcc, subject, etc.)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6548570/url-to-compose-a-message-in-gmail-with-full-gmail-interface-and-specified-to-b)