# mailto: new window but 'To' field address is mailto:user@test.com

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having a javascript to open a mail client in a new window to send an e-mail:

```
<a onClick="javascript:window.open('mailto:user@test.com', 'Mail');event.preventDefault()" href="mailto:user@test.com">Send a e-mail</a>
```

But the issue is that when Yahoo / Gmail clients compose pages opens up the '**To**' field is set to "**mailto:user@test.com**" by default which should actually be "**user@test.com**"

How can we achieve the same - I need to open the e-mail client on a new page only

HTML Code - please note that it would open an iframe window as target:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="ltr">
<head>
<style>
span {
    float: left;
    width: 0.7em;
    font-size: 400%;
    font-family: algerian, courier;
    line-height: 80%;
}
p {
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    line-height: 200%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<hr align="centre" width="50%"/> 
<p align="justify">
<img src="./images/dev.jpg" align="left" width="300px height="400px" hspace="20"/>
<strong><span>A</strong></span>t a time ... </p>
<h1>Contact:</h1>
<p align="justify">
<a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">Google</a><br/>
Professor<br/>
<a href="mailto:user@test.com" target="_blank">Send An e-mail</a>
<a onClick="window.open('mailto:user@test.com', 'Mail');event.preventDefault();" href="mailto:user@test.com">Send a e-mail</a>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: OT: you don't need `javascript:` in `onclick` attributes. That's only needed when you put JS in an attribute that normally contains a URL.

Comment: Why are you using javascript? You can get the same behavior just using the mailto in the href attribute.

Comment: Well it does not opens a new page - it uses the default page making user to move out from the application

Comment: So just add the target="_blank" attribute. Check out @dr_dev answer.

Comment: Firebug shows me opening the below URL in order: https://compose.mail.yahoo.com/?To=mailto%3Auser%40test.com then  https://in-mg61.mail.yahoo.com/neo/launch?action=compose&.rand=xxxxxxx#to=mailto%3Auser%40text.com

Comment: Well it is not opening in a new window

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because google & yahoo expect the url to have query strings of "?to=" instead of "?mailto=" 
See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4982702/what-is-the-format-of-compose-links-to-web-mail-clients-such-as-gmail-yahoo-mai) for more details

Comment: Thanks - I was thinking issue is with my code. Then I understand we do not have a way to rectify this as we do not know which client would user choose any way

Answer (score 1):

You have specified the url in window.open to be "mailto:user@test.com", that is the reason why it's opening that url in a new window. If your requirement is to open the mail client with the mentioned address i.e "user@test.com", you can simplty do it with the below line.

```
<a href="mailto:user@test.com?Subject=Mail" target="_blank">Send an e-mail</a>
```

Comment: Well I have the window in a iframe, and when I put your code to test the e-mail client does not opens in a new page

Comment: change the target value to "_top" and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

> Please try this,in the below example no need to use javascript.

```
<a href="mailto:user@test.com?Subject=Mail" target="_top">Send Mail</a>
```

> for [MORE DETAILS](http://www.rapidtables.com/web/html/mailto.htm)

Comment: It is not opening in a new window

Comment: @Prakash:Keenan Lidral-Porter is correct.. yahoo & google accept "to" instead of "mailto" :)

Answer (score -1):

Well I'm using latest chrome version(39.*) and Both the "Send an e-mail" and "Send a e-mail" links opens a new tab page for me..

Since I have configure my browser to open `mailto` links to open with Gmail by default, it opens gmail page with a compose window open where the `to` field is set to `user@test.com` and not `mailto:user@test.com`

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lakshman/Lsue6wcb/1/)